# How to optimize for returning a list for debug purposes

Tags: java

I would like to use the optimized code for elegance, but sometimes we have to debug and I change the code as follows. Is there an elegant way to do this

Optimized code

> ```
> return fetchFoos();
> ```

For debug purposes

> ```
> List<Foo> foos =  fetchFoos();
> log.trace("print foos {}", foos);
> return foos;
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new static method, which takes the argument you want to trace and returns it. It might look like this:

```
public static <T> T traceIt(T obj)
{
    log.trace("prints foos {}", obj);
    return obj;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
return Util.traceIt(fetchFoos());
```

If you want to adjust the text to print, you can add a new parameter to the `traceIt()` method.

```
public static <T> T traceIt(T obj, String prefix)
{
    log.trace("{}: {}", prefix, obj);
    return obj;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
return Util.traceIt(fetchFoos(), "foos");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `DEBUG` flag to differentiate when you are merely returning and / or printing for debugging purposes, as seen below. This debugging flag could be set manually or within the build options of your `IDE`.

```
if DEBUG
    log.trace("print foos {}", fetchFoos()); // No need for a list just pass it directly.
return foos;
```